# How to select in jQuery: #menu ul li:hover > ul?

Tags: jquery, hover, parent-child

How to select in jQuery an equivalent of `#menu ul li:hover > ul` ?

I would like to change the color of a box when hover is only on `li` TARGET

For more details, see: http://jsfiddle.net/wGbwX/18/

Comment: Don't use jQuery for css. Normal CSS is alot faster and smoother in every case.

Comment: Are you saying that whenever you hover over `<a>` with the text `TARGET`, you want that to trigger the hover event?  Your question is not very clear and you're getting a lot of answers that don't look even vaguely correct because people are guessing what you mean.  If that is what you want then just add a class to the `<a>` and do `$(".className").hover()`

Comment: Sorry, my English is a little bit basic. I'm saying whenever I hover over #menu ul li:hover but only with a ul child (=sub menu) I want to trigger the hover event.

Comment: No worries :)  I think I understand now.  I'll update your jsfiddle and post an answer.

Comment: So you don't want the hover event triggered when over the child elements?  Just the li?

Comment: Yes, just the li (first level) BUT only if this li (first level) has an immediate ul child. In css I use #menu ul li:hover > ul to select these specific li but how to do the same thing with jQuery ?

Answer (score 1):

You could hover the parent of nested uls:

```
$('#menu ul > li >ul').parent().hover
```

EDITED to reflect pebbl's recomendation of using selecting nested li's

Updated JS fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wGbwX/23/

Comment: +1 seems to be exactly what the OP wants :) If it were me though I'd use the child selector as well - just to avoid nested problems - so `$("#menu ul > li > ul").parent()`

Comment: Yep \0/ it could be my solution. Thank you all for your help :-)

Comment: I would add a `>` after `#menu` too `$("#menu > ul > li > ul")`. As this solution can still lead to nested problems. (If there were 3 or more `ul` nested inside each others)

Answer (score 1):

Since your `TARGET` is in an `a` tag you can use the following:

```
$('#menu > ul > li > a')
```

The `>` is to select the immediate child of each parent. Then finally bind the hover event on the `a` tag instead of the `li`.

The reason for using all those `>` in the selectors, is so that the selector doesn't select the `a` tag that are inside the TARGET `li`.

**Edit:**

Since the `HOME` link should not trigger the hover event, you can use one of the following:
<sup>Both will select the same items, but the logic is different.</sup>

```
$('#menu>ul>li:gt(0) > a')
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGbwX/27/).
This will make use of the [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector.

```
$('#menu>ul>li:not(:first) > a')
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGbwX/25/).
while this is a combination of the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and the [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). jsfiddle.

**Edit 2:**
Ok sorry, now I understand the requirements of the question.

[Joel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12817801/535122) works, but if you wanted to do the whole thing in the selector, you can do the following:

```
$('#menu > ul > li:has(ul) > a')
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGbwX/31/).
This will make use of the the [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector.
I tend to prefer this solution, for the single fact that, if I needed to return to this code later on, or someone else wanted to review the code, the goal of the selector can be easily understood by reading it.

> I am selecting an `anchor` inside a `list item` which contains an `unordered list`, etc...

Comment: yes but in your example, the hover event triggers on all li (Home and TARGET). I just want to trigger the hover event on li with an immediate ul child (TARGET) not the other (Home)

Comment: It's exactly what I want but the problem is that I don't know in advance wich li will have a ul child. (I use a CMS for a customer) It could be the first but it could be an other one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#menu ul:first > li > a')
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wGbwX/24/).

Answer (score 0):

i think this works:

but only for jquery 1.4 and higher

$("#menu ul li ul li").hover(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/ejazaz/7/edit)

```
$('#menu ul li a').hover(

    function(e) {
      change = $(this).parent().find(".sub-nav").length;
      if(change)
      {
        $('.toto').css({'background-color':'#cccccc'});
      }

    },
    function() { $('.toto').css({'background-color':'#f8f8f8'}); }
 );
```